# gremlin query involving edge property quantity checks

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, traversal

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZw00.jpg) schema for the graph database.

I need to find users who have `picked` calls from all `calls` labels that it is connected to, for `program` X.

I am quite new to gremlin and my vocabulary is limited.

I want to find a way to check if the number of incoming edges to users with `picked == yes` is the same as the total number of incoming edges to the user for a given `program` X. (that is, if every edge from program X to user via calls contains picked==yes)

I am unable to count twice in the same query and compare those values to decide if user satisfies criteria. My approach is as follows:

```
g.V().hasLabel("User").filter(inE().count().is(neq(0))).filter(inE().outV().in().has("program","name","X")).filter(inE().has("connected","yes").has("picked","no").count().is(eq(0))).values("name")
```

Essentially, I am removing all cases that I know do not lead to my expeced result (null nodes in User, Users who connected but did not pick up). This does not generate the right output when I tested it against manual examination result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the description alone I would say that this is your query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('User').
  filter(project('a','b').
           by(inE().has('picked','yes').count()).
           by(out().has('program','X').count()).
         where('a',eq('b')))
```

If that doesn't return the expected result, then please provide a snippet that creates a small sample graph along with the expected result.